# How to make a correct proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

> We have ${p_1, p_2,..., p_k}$ which is a set of prime integers. Show that if p prime divide $p^{e_{1}}_{1} \times p^{e_{2}}_{2} \times ... \times p^{e_{k}}_{k}$ for $e_i \in N^*$ for each $1 \leq i \leq k$ there exists $1 \leq i \leq k$ such that $p = p_i$

**Proof.** Let $m \in N^*$ and m = $p^{e_{1}}_{1} \times p^{e_{2}}_{2} \times ... \times p^{e_{k}}_{k}$ by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

We know that p divide $p^{e_{1}}_{1} \times p^{e_{2}}_{2} \times ... \times p^{e_{k}}_{k}$ therefore $p$ divides $m$.

Because of the added fact p is prime that means tha p is included in the sequence that forms m by the Euclid's theorem. So we can see that p divide $p^{e_{1}}_{1}$ or $p^{e_{2}}_{2}$ or... so one.

Because $m$ is formed of prime numbers multiplied together it is necessary that it will contain $p$ in it if $p$ divide $m$.

So we can conclude that here exists $1 \leq i \leq k$ such that $p = p_i$ is true. $\blacksquare$

---

Is my proof well constructed? If no I would like to be explained what is wrong exactly. If my proof is false I would like to be given a correct one.

Comment: Your proof uses "it is obvious" there. Why is it obvious? Why can't $m$ be written in two different ways as the product of primes. You are missing the main theorem here.

Comment: Recall the definition of [prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element#Relationship_with_prime_elements): $$p\mid ab\implies p\mid a\text{ or }p\mid b$$ Above, I link to the entry for "Irreducible Element" since the entry for "[Prime Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number)" gives the wrong definition; the one that seems to be cited in numerous articles for non-mathematicians.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your proof is formal enough. Let us examine it:

> Let $m \in \mathbb{N}^*$ and $m = p^{e_{1}}_{1} \cdot p^{e_{2}}_{2} \cdot ... \cdot p^{e_{k}}_{k}$ by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

You're given that $m = p^{e_{1}}_{1} \cdot p^{e_{2}}_{2} \cdot ... \cdot p^{e_{k}}_{k}$ in the exercise; However, if you still want to mention the fundamental theorem, I prefer it to be: "let $m \in \mathbb{N}^*$; by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, $m$ has a unique factorization $m = p^{e_{1}}_{1} \cdot p^{e_{2}}_{2} \cdot ... \cdot p^{e_{k}}_{k}$".

> We know that $p$ divides $p^{e_{1}}_{1} \cdot p^{e_{2}}_{2} \cdot ... \cdot p^{e_{k}}_{k}$ therefore $p$ divides $m$.

It may be just "It is given that $p$ divides $m = p^{e_{1}}_{1} \cdot p^{e_{2}}_{2} \cdot ... \cdot p^{e_{k}}_{k}$".

> Because of the added fact $p$ is prime that means that $p$ is included in the sequence that forms m by Euclid's theorem. So we can see that $p$ divide $p^{e_{1}}_{1}$ or $p^{e_{2}}_{2}$ or... so one. Because $m$ is formed of prime numbers multiplied together it is necessary that it will contain $p$ in it if $p$ divide $m$. So we can conclude that here exists $1 \leq i \leq k$ such that $p = p_i$ is true.

Here is the considerable problem in your proof; You haven't shown that explicitly. You should write: "$p$ is prime and it divides $m$, so there exists some $i$ such that $p \vert p_i$ - we will show a stronger statement: If $m=m_1 \cdot ... \cdot m_t$ for some integers $m_1, ... m_t$ (not necessarily primes), then $p \vert m_i$ for some $i$. We show this by induction on $k$:

- If $k=1$, that is $m=m_1$, then $p \vert m_1 = m$.
- Let $k$ be an arbitrary integer, $m = m_1 \cdot ... \cdot m_k$; Let us divide $m$ by $p$: $m_1 \cdot ... \cdot m_k = p \cdot x$ for some $x$. If $p$ divides $m_1$ we are done, otherwise, as $p$ divides a multiplication of two numbers $m_1 \cdot (m_2 \cdot ... \cdot m_k)$, and by Euclid's lemma $p$ divides one of them (or both); But as $p$ doesn't divide $m_1$, it divides $(m_2 \cdot ... \cdot m_k)$, and finally by inductive hypothesis, there exists some $2 \leq i \leq k$ such that $p \vert m_i$.

It finishes the proof because $m = p_1 \cdot ... \cdot p_1 \cdot ... \cdot p_k \cdot ... \cdot p_k$ and we have shown that $p \vert p_i$ for some $i$. The only two divisors of a prime number ($p_i$) are $1$ and $p_i$, but $p$ is prime and therefore cannot be $1$. So, $p = p_i$".

If you are not allowed to use Euclid's lemma (that says that if a prime $p$ divides $a \cdot b$ then $p \vert a$ or $p \vert b$), prove it.

Comment: Hi, please accept the answer or tell me if you want some further explanations